# In Apple Calendar 11 for Mac, is there a keyboard shortcut to save a new entry?

Tags: mac, keyboard, calendar

I would like to save a new calendar entry using a keyboard shortcut. At the moment, after filling in the necessary fields, I have to click outside the entry box to save it. I've looked online and tried a few instinctive keyboard shortcuts without success.

Comment: The Enter key.. will open it & close it again.

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem.  The workflow I use (Monterey, Cal v11) is: Cmd-Tab to Calendar, Cmd-N to open "Create Quick Event", type details like "11am test", press Return to display event edit event info, press Return to close event info and "Save" (although its already saved after the first Return)

Comment: @CharlesLindsay - Calendar has no "Save". It constantly saves & syncs your last edit.

Comment: Pressing return works, though it didn't at the time of posting this question - probably just a temporary blip in the app.